# Polymer workflow and architecture

Tags: polymer

I'd like to ask you people about workflow with Polymer. I know that I should use my own elements or double check if element that I need isn't alredy published. It's really nice, I admit it. However the Polymer Starter Kit comes as single-page app. Is it the recommended approach for using Polymer? What about large pages that would need a lot of data to be loaded? Are there alternative approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have all your elements rendered at same time. They can be created on the fly only when needed, and can be destroyed as well.

To create your elements on the fly, you can use DOM Manipulation methods like:

```
var myElement = document.createElement("my-element");
this.$.container.appendChild(myElement);
myElement.myProperty = "anything";
```

To remove, just do this way:

```
var myElement = this.$.container.querySelector("my-element");
myElement.parentNode.removeChild(myElement);
```

If you need dynamic load a HTML Import, you can use this.importHref if your code is inside a polymer Element (and it should be).

```
this.importHref('myElement.html', function(e) {
    // Create your element here
});
```

*Putting things together...*

Suppose you have a polymer element like that:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <paper-button on-click="_loadElement">Load Element</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-click="_removeElement">Remove Element</paper-button>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-app',
        _loadElement: function() {
            this.importHref('myElement.html', function(e) {
                var myElement = document.createElement("my-element");
                this.$.container.appendChild(myElement);
                myElement.myProperty = "anything";
            });
        },
        _removeElement: function() {
            var myElement = this.$.container.querySelector("my-element");
            myElement.parentNode.removeChild(myElement);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I created a post here with more details about that topic: https://easyusedev.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/dynamically-loading-polymer-elements-on-the-fly/